# DisplayActionSheet not showing

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using `MessagingCenter` to signal a `MasterDetailPage` from my model.

```cs
private void ShowActionSheet(object sender, IEnumerable<string> hosts)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        // Works
        await DisplayAlert("Testing!", "Some text", "OK");

        // Does not work
        await DisplayActionSheet("Test", "Cancel", "Destroy", new[] {"1","2"});
    }
}
```

When calling `DisplayActionSheet` I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7e737aa0> on <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_NavigationRenderer: 0x7e4b31a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

There's a "Please wait"-modal on top of the MasterDetailPage. It works without the modal, but that's not really an acceptable solution.

Any tips or pointers will be appreciated.

---

UPDATE: I've moved `DisplayActionSheet` to the modal as a last resort. I still fear that this issue is iOS 8.2 related.

Comment: I think this issue started when I upgraded my Build Host to iOS 8.2

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms do you use?

Comment: I was using 1.3.5.6335, and updated to 1.4.0.6341 to see if that fixed it. It did not.

Comment: Well, ActionSheets are presented in their own UIWindow, I believe. UIWindows are handled by the OS, by the way. It is strongly recommended not to try creating more UIWindows aside from the one that you create at app startup, or even try to manually manage the UIWindow collection. But anyway, since action sheet is in a UIWindow that is managed by the OS, there may be something wacky going on there.

Answer (score 0):

change your code:

Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500), ShowActionSheet);

```
async Task<bool> ShowActionSheet()
{
    await DisplayActionSheet("Test", "Cancel", "Destroy", new[] {"1","2"});
    return false;
}
```