# Xamarin.iOS DisplayActionSheet doesn't show

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm building an application with Xamarin.Forms and a Portable Class Library. I am using a `DisplayActionSheet`. It works fine and shows up on Android and UWP.

However, the `DisplayActionSheet` doesn't show up on iOS (iPhone and iPad). I don't know why, there is no error, it just doesn't show up. This is the code:

```
public async void OnActionSheetSimpleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e, CachedImage image)
{
     var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Info Popup", "Cancel", null, "thing 1", "thing 2", "thing 3");
}
```

I have a `ListView` with a datatemplate which contains a `CachedImage`. The `CachedImage` has a `TapGestureRecognizer` which calls the function `OnActionSheetSimpleClicked`.

My question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235221/displayactionsheet-not-showing), because I do not get a warning and do not use a `MasterDetailPage`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how I could fix this?

EDIT:
I'm using Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.175

Comment: What happens when you're debugging?

Comment: Nothing happens, it just doesn't show up.

Comment: Make sure you are on the latest Xamarin Forms version perhaps? I just tried to reproduce the issue but could not, running your code in a Forms app deployed to an IOS simulator worked as expected. Maybe check that the OnActionSheetSimpleClicked is actually being called? Issue may be with the TapGestureRecognizer not firing the method.

Comment: The TapGestureRecognizer is fired for sure, and so is OnActionSheetSimpleClicked. I'm trying to update to the latest version of Xamarin.Forms now, this could be the problem. @jgoldberger

Comment: @jgoldberger I updated to the latest version of Xamarin.Forms but it still doesn't show up..

Comment: Very odd. Is there any way you can post a simple test project that shows the issue?

Comment: Hey @jgoldberger I did sent you a chat via de chat of stackoverflow. I can provide you a simple test project.

Comment: Hmm, never used SO chat... and I don't see it anywhere. Perhaps post your project to dropbox or similar service and share the link? UPDATE: Ah, found it. Replied.

Comment: Thanks for the test project. I could reproduce the issue. You did have mismatched versions of Forms, e.g. 2.2.0.31 in Droid and PCL project, but 2.3.3.175 in the iOS project. However fixing that made no difference. Since I can not reproduce this issue in a simpler project, I suspect something with the libraries you are using, perhaps the FFImageLoading library? Not sure. You should file a bug report.
bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug
Here are the guidelines for filing a bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/page.cgi?id=bug-writing.html
You will have to create an account on that system.

Comment: I did notice that when the DisplayActionSheet gets called, on iOS it never returns, IOW the next line of code is never run, so for some reason that call is failing but I see nothing in the app output or device logs to indicate why. Calling DisplayActionSheet elsewhere in your code works, like in the OnAppearing override for the page.

Comment: I did file a bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=49788